# VMWare-Mount not recognizing virtual disks

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, virtualization, mount

I have two disks as `.vmdk` files, and four as `.vdi` files. I can boot virtual machines on them with Sun xMV VirtualBox, and they work just fine. However, I want to mount them on my local computer so I can read some files off of them without starting a virtual machine. I downloaded the `vmware-mount` utility, but I get this error:

```
Unable to mount the virtual disk. The disk may be in use by a virtual
machine, may not have enough volumes or mounted under another drive
letter. If not, verify that the file is a valid virtual disk file.
```

Thinking it's a problem with the utility, I downloaded the SDK and made my own simple program in C to try to mount a disk. It just initializes the API, connects to it, then attempts to open the disk. I get this error, once again claiming it is not a virtual disk:

```
**LOG: DISKLIB-DSCPTR: descriptor above max size: I64u
**LOG: DISKLIB-LINK  : "f:\programming\VMs\windowstrash.vdi" : failed to open (The file specified is not a virtual disk).
**LOG: DISKLIB-CHAIN : "f:\programming\VMs\windowstrash.vdi" : failed to open (The file specified is not a virtual disk).
**LOG: DISKLIB-LIB   : Failed to open 'f:\programming\VMs\windowstrash.vdi' with flags 0x1e (The file specified is not a virtual disk).
** FAILURE ** : The file specified is not a virtual disk
```

The files are clearly virtual disks, though, since I can actually mount and use them with a virtual machine. I tried detaching them from any VMs and trying again, but I got the same results.

Any ideas? Maybe the "descriptor above max size" is a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.vdi` is a VirtualBox supported format, but not supported by VMWare.

The `.vmdk` files are VMWare images - you should be able to load them fine using the vmware tool (VirtualBox supports these too, but the converse is not true).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to just mount the VDI image, try these steps as described at http://bethesignal.org/blog/2011/01/05/how-to-mount-virtualbox-vdi-image/ :

- Be the super user, using `sudo su`
- Load the nbd kernel module (the network block device module), using `modprobe nbd`
- run `qemu-nbd` using `qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 <vdi-file>`. This is a user space loopback block device server for QEMU-supported disk images. Basically, it knows all about weird disk image formats, and presents them to the kernel via nbd, and ultimately to the rest of the system as if they were a normal disk.

That command will expose the entire image as a block device named `/dev/nbd0`, and the partitions within it as subdevices. For example, the first partition in the image will appear as `/dev/nbd0p1`.

Now you could, for instance, run `cfdisk` on the block device, but you will most likely want to mount an individual partition:

```
mount /dev/nbd0p1 /mnt
```

When you’re done, unmount the filesystem and shut down the qemu-nbd service:

```
umount /mnt
qemu-nbd -d /dev/nbd0
```